# Entity Framework includes the unexpected child if the child is ready called in another statement

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1.2, Pomelo.EntityFramework 3.1.1 to link with a MySQL database. Here is a minimum example to demonstrate my problem.

Two model classes are defined. The model `Field` includes multiple zones:

```cs
public class Field
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Zone> Zones { get; set; }

    public Field()
    {
        Zones = new HashSet<Zone>();
    }
}

public class Zone
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int FieldId { get; set; }
    public virtual Field Field { get; set; }
}
```

Then an API is created to get the data for a zone.

```cs
[Route("api/field/{field}/zone/{id}")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<Field>>> GetZone(
    [FromRoute] int field,
    [FromRoute] int id)
{
    Zone Zone = await _context.Zone
                              .Where(m => m.FieldId == field && m.Id == id)
                              .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    return Ok(_context.Field);
}
```

In the demo code, I expect to return the list of `Field` without `Zone`. However, the results include the contents for `Zone` equals `id` if calling `/api/field/16/zone/15`.

```
[
    {
        "zone": [],
        "id": 7
    },
    {
        "zone": [
            {
                "id": 15
            }
        ],
        "id": 16
    }
]
```

It seems the contents are kept if the child is called in another place. I would not want to return child. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related with Tracking behavior in Entity Framework Core. See this link for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking

Using function `AsNoTracking()` will solve my problem.

```cs
return Ok(_context.Field.AsNoTracking());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add   `[JsonIgnore]` and `[IgnoreDataMember]` attributes in the `Zones` property in `Field` class.

```
 public class Field
        {
            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            [JsonIgnore]
            [IgnoreDataMember]
            public virtual ICollection<Zone> Zones { get; set; }

            public Field()
            {
                Zones = new HashSet<Zone>();
            }
        }
```

More details, please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18223985/12884742).

Comment: Thanks. However jsonignore attribute totally ignore in all API request. I would like to have it in other request.